# Android Studio - Gradle can't resolve appcompat-v7:23.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have started a new Project with Android Studio 2.0 Preview 3b

I have SDK updated.

But when the project has been created, gradle launch error message:
[image]

That's how lok `build.gradle` (module) file:(auto-generated by AS)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

And `build.gradle` (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I click on the first option from the error log, AS opens this window:

[image]

Finally say that I have

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: update your build tool

Comment: Hey Shudy! Long time no see :) You don't need that dependency since is included in the design one already:

+--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar

Comment: Build->Clean, Then Rebuild And Sync

Comment: +IntelliJ Amiya , not really, I got new laptop on work,  and had to reinstall everything... and for some reason, this not happened again ..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved uninstalling Android Studio. The real problem was SDK. When you uninstalling AS SDK is still on computer, and I deleted all these files from SDK folder. The best option if you install AS and SDK directly on C:. After that AS working without any problems.